# SQL query to find deltas between multiple series in time-series data

Tags: sql, postgresql, iot, timescaledb

I have IoT time-series data in Timescale DB (PostgreSQL) that looks like this:

| time | device_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-28 16:49:51+00 | device_05 | sensor_1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:49:51+00 | device_05 | sensor_2 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:16+00 | device_01 | sensor_1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:16+00 | device_01 | sensor_2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:24+00 | device_03 | sensor_1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:24+00 | device_03 | sensor_2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:52+00 | device_06 | sensor_2 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:52+00 | device_06 | sensor_1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:56+00 | device_15 | sensor_2 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:56+00 | device_15 | sensor_1 | 0 |

I would like to write a SQL query to find discrepencies among sensors on the same device at a given time. In the above example data, `device_03` has sensors that are reporting conflicting values.

| time | device_id | delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-28 16:49:51+00 | device_05 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:16+00 | device_01 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:24+00 | device_03 | 1 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:52+00 | device_06 | 0 |
| 2022-01-28 16:50:56+00 | device_15 | 0 |

Each device reports data from all of its sensors at the same time, so let's assume that the timestamps will be the same. (However, if it's not terribly more complicated, it would be nice to handle the case where this is not guaranteed, in which case the last known value applies.)

Answer (score 1):

Aha, it was a matter of combining `GROUP BY` with `COUNT(DISTINCT())`!

```
SELECT
    "time",
    device_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(value)) - 1 AS "delta"
FROM
    data
WHERE measurement = 'sensors'
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Just to say there's a recent post on the Timescale blog that covers 'last value' you might find interesting? Sorry I missed the original question. (transparency: I work for Timescale).

Comment: Fantastic; I hadn't seen that. Thanks. I need to follow that blog!